# Exportable JavaScript class in index.html not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get confident in using Exportable Classes in JavaScript. But somehow in my index.html the console says that my App class is not defined. Had tried different solutions but none of them work.

Here is my Code, maybe i am missing something?

index.html:

```
<script>
    import App from "./App.js";
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
       <title>Infoscreen</title>
       <script type="module" src="App.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="App">
          <script type="module">
              var app = new App();
          </script>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

App.js:

```
import TemplateReader from './Src/TemplateReader.js';

export class App {
   constructor(){
       this.appNode = document.getElementsByClassName("App")[0];
       this.displayHtml();
   }

   displayHtml(){
       var teRe = new TemplateReader();
       this.appNode.innerHTML = teRe.readSingleFile("./Templates/test.html");    
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are exporting the class directly, as `export class App {../code here}`, you should import it as: `import {App} from './App.js'`

And as a small addition, it is bad practice to write js code directly inside the html.